# pytorch: simple recurrent neural network for image classification

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am making a simple recurrent neural network architecture for CIFAR10 image classification. I am not interested not use pre-defined RNN class in PyTorch because i am implementing from scratch according to figure. I am getting input tensor errors in the same device.  I am not sure whether my code is right or wrong. Any simple way to write FC layer without defining shape and hard coded parameters.

**Figure**

[image]

**Code**

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_classes):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.input_to_hidden = nn.Linear(in_features=input_size + hidden_size, out_features=output_size)
        self.input_to_output = nn.Linear(in_features=input_size + hidden_size, out_features=output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, input_tensor):
        combined = torch.cat((input_tensor, torch.zeros(input_tensor.size(0))), 1)
        hidden = self.input_to_hidden(combined)
        output = self.input_to_output(combined)
        output = self.softmax(output)
        return output, hidden
```

**Trackback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_1/tutorials/rnn.py", line 81, in <module>
    outputs = model(images)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_1/tutorials/rnn.py", line 33, in forward
    combined = torch.cat((input_tensor, torch.zeros(input_tensor.size(0))), 1)
RuntimeError: All input tensors must be on the same device. Received cuda:0 and cpu
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the tensors are on the same device (cpu/gpu) before you are contacting them

you can add a device parameter to your class and use it:

```
    class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_classes, device='cuda'):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.device = device
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.input_to_hidden = nn.Linear(in_features=input_size + hidden_size, out_features=output_size)
        self.input_to_output = nn.Linear(in_features=input_size + hidden_size, out_features=output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, input_tensor):
        combined = torch.cat((input_tensor.to(device), torch.zeros(input_tensor.size(0), device=self.device)), 1)
        hidden = self.input_to_hidden(combined)
        output = self.input_to_output(combined)
        output = self.softmax(output)
        return output, hidden
```